# Auth0 management api getting error when error while trying to get user details after login

Tags: node.js, express, backend, auth0

I am facing issue with getting user details after login with auth0. Below is the error response and the actual implementation for the same. I need to know what is the approach for getting detail after login i am getting access_token in response after login i need to get use rdetails but not able to do that getting error invalid token.

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Invalid token",
        "statusCode": 401,
        "requestInfo": {
            "method": "get",
            "url": "https://dev-e48f02pgr13we72c.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C64c888b07f18450dc24cb099"
        },
        "originalError": {
            "status": 401,
            "response": {
                "req": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": "https://dev-e48f02pgr13we72c.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C64c888b07f18450dc24cb099",
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "user-agent": "node.js/18.16.1",
                        "auth0-client": "eyJuYW1lIjoibm9kZS1hdXRoMCIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIzLjYuMCIsImVudiI6eyJub2RlIjoiMTguMTYuMSJ9fQ",
                        "authorization": "[REDACTED]",
                        "accept": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                "header": {
                    "date": "Tue, 01 Aug 2023 06:51:00 GMT",
                    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "content-length": "106",
                    "connection": "close",
                    "cf-ray": "7efc2669a9ac4ad4-HYD",
                    "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache",
                    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
                    "vary": "origin, Accept-Encoding",
                    "www-authenticate": "Bearer error=\"Invalid token\"",
                    "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
                    "ot-baggage-auth0-request-id": "7efc2669a9ac4ad4",
                    "ot-tracer-sampled": "true",
                    "ot-tracer-spanid": "1ac1e404795ebcc4",
                    "ot-tracer-traceid": "1a534d0a01d9f0ea",
                    "traceparent": "00-00000000000000001a534d0a01d9f0ea-1ac1e404795ebcc4-01",
                    "tracestate": "auth0-request-id=7efc2669a9ac4ad4,auth0=true",
                    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
                    "server": "cloudflare",
                    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=86400"
                },
                "status": 401,
                "text": "{\"statusCode\":401,\"error\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"Invalid token\",\"attributes\":{\"error\":\"Invalid token\"}}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing issue with getting user details after login with auth0. Below is the error response and the actual implementation for the same. I need to know what is the approach for getting detail after login i am getting access_token in response after login i need to get use rdetails but not able to do that getting error invalid token.

Implementation:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { AuthenticationClient, ManagementClient } = require('auth0');

dotenv.config();

const auth0 = new AuthenticationClient({
  domain: process.env.DOMAIL,
  clientId:process.env.CLIENT_ID
  clientSecret:  process.env.SECRET,
});

const management = new ManagementClient({
  domain: process.env.DOMAIL,
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SECRET,
  audience: process.env.AUDIENCE,
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Attempt to authenticate the user with Auth0's Resource Owner Password Grant
    const response = await auth0.passwordGrant({
      username: username, // Allow login with either email or username
      password,
      audience: "https://dev-e48f02pgr13we72c.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
      scope: 'openid profile email', // Add any additional scopes as needed
    });

    console.log(response.access_token);
    // Fetch user data including roles using the Management API
    const user = await management.getUser({ id:"auth0|64c888b07f18450dc24cb099"})

    console.log(user);



    // Return the access token and user information
    res.status(200).json({ accessToken: response.access_token, user: response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during login:', error.message);
    res.status(401).json({ error: error });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```